# fluid grid - width in percent but horizontal scroll bar appears

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have header and horizontal navi bar set at 100% width and that seems to work properly, but my div with content not. 
Even if i set width to 90% and i shrink browser window, the horizontal bar appears at some point (but at a little lower horizontal width than when it's set to 100%).

Why is that happening ?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening without your code...

Comment: Yeah, im preparing jsfiddle right now, sorry, i forgot about it at first.

Comment: Nevermind, i found out what was causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind. When i was making jsfiddle to show my problem, i found out what's causing it.

### Solution

If anyone have the same problem, in my case, that was becaouse of padding and margin in px, so width was 90% + 30px (which at some point is more than 10% of full width).